# Play, passing request around to views

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to scala/web desing/mvc/play/internet(no). 
Using MVC. Need to pass debug info around, debug info is a subset of the Request. 
Info flow: COntroller calls each view, view generates data and then passes to main to display as a whole. Main also shows debug info. 
Currently extracting debug info in Controller, and passing it to each view which in turn passes to main which shows debug info. 
This doesn't seem right, should controller be passing this info to each the views for them to just transfer this to main? Is there a way for main to directly get it.

(Hopefully I've kept the question brief and clear, happy to explain more if it isn't clear..)

Comment: Some sample code (even if it doesn't work) would help explain what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the request header directly to main. You must specify it for every sub template if you declare it on the main template. Then you can pass the RequestHeader around by defining it implicit in your action and in your views.

Your action must look like:

```
def example = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.example("Example"))
}
```

Your sub template must look like:

```
@(title: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@main(title) {
    <p>My request path is: @request.path</p>
}
```

And your main template must look like:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>@html</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I made the codeflow as you suggested, and see the implicit request.